# Want to update parent object field from child object field using trigger

Tags: trigger

I have two object library(Parent) and book(child) with the same field PublishDate__c my requirement is when the child record  inserted and i want from child object PublishDate__c value  auto update in Library(parent) object PublishDate__c field with the help of trigger.

Comment: Sounds like something best done by making Library.PublishDate__c the MAX(Child. PublishDate__c) - see the [Roll-Up Summary Field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ie%2F&type=5) documentation.

Comment: I don't think so Roll-Up Summary will help on that, i want to achieve that using trigger.

Comment: Are you looking to store many PublishDate__c values from Child to Parent? Or just the latest updated Child?

Comment: when the latest child record created then PublishDate__c values will update in Library(parent) PublishDate__c field value mean "just the latest updated Child".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple aggregate result query for this:

```
trigger updatePublishDate on Child__c(after insert) {
  // Aggregate all parent Ids
  Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
  for(Child__c record: Trigger.new) {
    parentIds.add(record.Parent__c);
  }
  // Query for the max value for each parent
  Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT Parent__c Id, MAX(PublishDate__c) maxDate
    FROM Child__c
    WHERE Parent__c = :parentIds
    GROUP BY Parent__c]);
  // Update parents
  Parent__c[] parents = new Parent__c[0];
  for(Id recordId: results.keySet()) {
    parents.add(
      new Parent__c(
        Id=recordId, 
        LatestPublishDate__c=(Id)results.get(recordId).get('maxDate')
      )
    };
  }
  update parents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
trigger UpdateLibraryDate on Child__c (before insert) {
    Id parentId;
    Date childDate;
    for(Child__c child : Trigger.new) {
        parentId = child.parent__c;
        childDate = child.PublishDate__c;
    }
    Parent__c parent = [SELECT Id, PublishDate__c FROM Parent__c WHERE id = : parentId];
    parent.PublishDate__c = childDate;
    update parent;
}
```

But I am afraid this wont work for bulk data. You need to bulkify this code.. But this can be workaround for time being.
I hope you will insert 1 book at a time.. otherwise it will update the date for latest book uploaded.